# Ansible apt_repository creating duplicate entries?

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, apt

I'm stuck trying to add a repo through Ansible. The result is two different repo files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ with different names, that conflict. This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.

This is from my vars yaml:

```
repos:
  - name: vscode
    repo: deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/packages.microsoft.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
    key: https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
    keyring: /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/packages.microsoft.gpg

  - name: foliate
    repo: ppa:apandada1/foliate
    keyserver: keyserver.ubuntu.com
    id: 95ACDEBD8BFF99ABE0F26A49A507B2BBA7803E3B
```

And this is from my task yaml:

```
- name: Install gpg keys
  apt_key:
    url: "{{ item.key | default(omit) }}"
    keyring: "{{ item.keyring | default(omit) }}"
    id: "{{ item.id | default(omit) }}"
    keyserver: "{{ item.keyserver | default(omit) }}"
  loop: "{{ repos }}"
  become: true

- name: Install repositories
  apt_repository:
    repo: "{{ item.repo }}"
  loop: "{{ repos }}"
  become: true
```

The result on the server is this:

```
# ls -1 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
...
packages_microsoft_com_repos_vscode.list
vscode.list

# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/packages_microsoft_com_repos_vscode.list 
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/packages.microsoft.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main

# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list 
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
```

Which leads to the error:

> "E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source
> https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/ stable:
> /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/packages.microsoft.gpg != ", "E: The list of
> sources could not be read."

So how come the additional repo file?

Comment: Contents of `vscode.list` does not match what you have in your `repos` variable. Ansible created `packages_microsoft_com_repos_vscode.list`. Obviously it's not possible to tell how that additional repo file was created.

Comment: I discovered it's a post-install script from VSCode but I haven't figured out how to disable it yet. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/resources/linux/debian/postinst.template

Answer (score 0):

if you add `filename: vscode` under the `apt_repository` section it will not create an extra `.list` file.